How to utilise geo JSON index (on collection) in Arango search query

I have created an index on the collection [Profiles]
Create a search view on the same collection.
Running the search query on the view (created on the same collection [Profiles]),
(Running search query on id and geo_location fields).
when I am running the explain query it is not using any index (showing index used "none").
please help me explain why it is not using any index.
Explain result: running query on view 
If running the query on the collection itself it is using the geo_location index.
Explain result: running query on collection 

Why it is not using the index on the search query?
